# Self Ether transaction

Tags: ether

Hi placed a self Ether transaction by error, where did the Ether go? can I recover it?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd64133abcd2205e76b8241af11bb081c23ce7e77016ec03660cc09a8866c9317

Answer (score 1):

The ether didn't go anywhere, it's still in that account. Any real Ethereum wallet should handle that and show the correct balance. Are you seeing an incorrect balance?

Answer (score 0):

The the amount that was sent disappeared (0.24)

https://etherscan.io/address/0x7f851abb81da1426be2d4f8b4484f279a6ff71b1